# ¿Cómo escribir y leer un Array en un archivo .dat en Java?

Tags: java, array

Investigando, creo que sé cómo se puede escribir un Array en un archivo .dat en Java, aunque no sé si será la manera correcta. Esto es lo que tengo para escribirlo:

```
try {
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("continuo.dat"));
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            out.write(continuo[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }                       
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR al crear el fichero");
    return;
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR al escribir en el fichero");
    return;
}
```

Pero no he conseguido información sobre cómo leerlo. ¿Cómo puede leer el Array de un archivo .dat en Java?

Comment: Asumiendo que el código escribe algo, estas usando el método de _Writer_ write(Char[] sequencia). Tus Strings estan separados por espacio. Si quieres leer los datos con readLine despues, deberías separar los Strings con out.newLine() entre los datos.

Answer (score 3):

Si el objetivo es simplemente poder guardar un arreglo a un archivo, y luego poder reconstruir el arreglo leyéndolo del archivo, sin importar el formato del archivo en sí, entonces puedes usar las clases [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) y [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) para hacer esto. En realidad, puedes usar estas clases para serializar cualquier objecto, siempre y cuando sea una de los tipos primitivos en Java (`int`, `float`, `String`, etc.) o esté marcada apropiadamente como serializable (por medio de implementar la interfaz [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)).

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo que puedes probar por tu cuenta:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // 1. crear arreglo.
    String[][] array = new String[2][];
    array[0] = new String[2];
    array[0][0] = "(0, 0)";
    array[0][1] = "(0, 1)";
    array[1] = new String[2];
    array[1][0] = "(1, 0)";
    array[1][1] = "(1, 1)";

    // 2. Escribir el arreglo al archivo.
    writeArray(array);

    // 3. Leer el arreglo del archivo.
    String[][] deserializedArray = readArray();

    // 4. Verificar contenidos del arreglo.
    for (String[] subArray : deserializedArray) {
        for (String item : subArray) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}

private static void writeArray(String[][] array) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("continuo.dat"))) {

        out.writeObject(array);
    }
}

private static String[][] readArray() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("continuo.dat"))) {

        return (String[][]) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

Si lo corres, verás que escribe y lee el arreglo correctamente, produciendo el resultado siguiente:

> (0, 0)
>   (0, 1)
>   (1, 0)
>   (1, 1)

Notarás que, cómo no especificastes el tipo de la variable `continuo` en tu código, usé el tipo `String[][]` para mi ejemplo. Pero, nuevamente, puedes usar cualquier tipo, mientras sea uno de los tipo primitivos en Java, o se trate de una clase que implemente la interfaz [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Si deseas más información, sigue los enlaces que te dejé arriba.

Comment: @Stefan: gracias por la edición. Eso sucede cuando tengo C# en mente, donde el estándar es diferente.

Comment: De nada, no soy fanático de mejores practicas, pero en estos casos ayudan en entender el código mejor (y no esperar C# donde hay Java :D ) para poder marcarlo como útil en buena consciencia.

Comment: @Stefan: Totalmente de acuerdo :)

Answer (score -1):

Obs:

- Como no tengo acceso al archivo continuo.dat puse que lea toda la cadena. La idea es que con este código se adapte a las necesidades, porque no tengo acceso al archivo .dat

En tu método donde va a contener la parte de código que lee tu archivo tenes que agregar throws IOException

Ejemplo:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ArchivoDAT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Leer archivo
        String cadena;
        FileReader f = new FileReader("continuo.dat");
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(cadena);
        }
        b.close();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Tengo importado java.io.* El problema es que yo quiero leer el array como un int, no como un string, no se si me explico.

Comment: @dfortu proba el código que coloque. Debería de funcionar. Después adapta a tu código. Dímelo si te funciona

Comment: readLine() no va funcionar aquí, no esta separando los Strings con newLine en su codigo.

Comment: @StefanNolde como no tenia acceso al archivo continuo.dat puse así. La idea es que con este código adapte a sus necesidades, porque no proporciono el archivo